# docker + why we cant kill the container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, rhel

we have Linux machine with the following container

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
6de660db9fdb        kafka-exporter:v1.9.0   "/bin/kafka_export"   23 hours ago        Up 17 hours                             kafka-export
```

we want to kill the container so we did that:

```
docker kill 6de660db9fdb
```

but its hang for along time ( more then hour and not killed )

any advice how to stop/kill the container ?

Comment: You could run `docker stop` and `docker rm` and if that does not work there is a `-f` flag for the `docker rm`. This will use `SIGKILL`.

Comment: I start with  docker stop 6de660db9fdb ,and this also take time , ( until now its not stooped )

Comment: Ok, then try `docker container rm -f 6de6`.

Comment: also tried the docker container rm -f 6de660db9fdb   , but after 1 min still hang )

Comment: Well, the last resort is to stop Docker completely then. :)

Comment: yes but when I stooped the docker then we have still a process that seems its part of the container - root     28326 28295 99 Oct18 ?        1-05:30:34 /bin/kafka_exporter --kafka.server=kafka1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238320/discussion-between-jessica-and-marko-e).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try restarting the Docker service first:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

And then removing the container with the force -f flag:

```
sudo docker rm -f 6de660db9fdb
```